# Using SESSION variables as validation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am still learning laravel

I have tables like this:

```
Item->ID
Item->User_ID
```

Now I get a selected item and set its ID as a session variable using this code:

```
public function get_item($id){
$selected_item = item::where('id',$id)->where('User_ID',Auth::user()->id)->first   

$request->session()->put('item_id', $selected_item->id);

}
```

Now with this SESSION variable I can do other things such as delete, edit etc:

```
public function delete_item(Request $request)
{
Item::where('id,$request->session()->get('item_id'))->delete();
}
```

Now some people has told me that this is good practice because I only reach the Database once and have it set until I select another item. Some people have said that I should still just use more Middleware instead of setting SESSION variables. Since I get such diverse opinions, would anyone tell me if this way is correct?

Comment: you can directly access the session variable and do it

Comment: What if the user has your site/app open in multiple browser tabs? The choice they make in one would override the session variable, and therefor the same id would be used in all other tabs after the next reload. Even more dangerous - the user selects a different id in tab #2, then comes back to tab #1, and presses delete there - they expect the item they saw in tab #1 to get deleted, but the id in the session has changed in between … oops? No, in this scenario you do absolute _not_ want to transport this piece of information via the session.

Comment: @CBroe you are right. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session is a wrong way. You have to pass id as query string and then perform edit, delete or you can use ajax and on button click you can pass the item ID and then perform operations like edit, delete.